# WPF app won't run in kiosk mode

Tags: wpf, kiosk

I have a WPF application that is designed for a touchscreen kiosk. Users will not have access to a keyboard or mouse. The application runs fine when started normally from the program icon in windows. However, when it is set up to run automatically at startup (by replacing the Windows shell using a registry key), the application does not function properly.

The application reads an XML file that lists available videos, then displays buttons to show the videos. When run in "kiosk mode," it does not seem to have access to the files in its media directory (the XML file and presumably the videos as well). I suspect that because the application is running in place of the windows explorer, it is missing resources it needs for file access that are normally loaded by windows explorer.

I have not been able to find any info on this - there is plenty of info on how to get an app to run at startup, but not much on how to make sure it will actually function in that environment. The PC is running Windows 7 Professional.

Is my assumption about the problem correct, or is it likely something else (e.g. permissions - we checked the permissions, but maybe they operate differently when you replace the windows shell?) If it is because needed resources are not loaded, does anyone have pointers on how to make sure my app loads them?

Comment: First, I know it is definitely possible to run WPF apps as explorer replacements, at least on XP. I've seen it done, nothing too special with the code base - and local file access was certainly being done. I guess I would have a question: What exceptions are you getting? If you're not logging those, check out event viewer if the app is crashing. How do you know file access is missing? Tell us more.

Given your requirements, do you need to actually replace the shell or would hiding the tray/changing desktop size be enough? Might make it easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks, we are trying to get more data on the errors. I don't think the full shell replacement is necessary, since public users will only have access to the touchscreen. The LAN Admin who set up the machine configured it that way because he thought it would be most secure. Our requirements are: no access to anything but the kiosk app, and automatically run the kiosk app whenever the PC is rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have file access occurring via a file dialog? This might explain a bit further. [What is the minimum functionality needed to create Shell Replacement for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730820/what-is-the-minimum-functionality-needed-to-create-shell-replacement-for-windows)

Comment: I am not using a file dialog, I am opening a StreamReader using a relative path. But I wonder if the StreamReader file access is still relying on explorer.exe for its IO... we are trying to get more info on the exact errors.

Answer (score 0):

because you have stopped windows default running explorer.exe , your program can not get access to default xml directory therefore you should specify the complete path for example like below:

```
stream = File.Open(@"C:\x86\Debug\xml.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```